# Google Weather API returning strange new error

Tags: api, weather, weather-api, google-weather-api

I'm using the Google Weather API in an iPhone app, and lately sometimes it has been returning a 403 error, but now it's returning a really funky error saying "Unknown API" no matter what location I enter into it.[Example here.](http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=Mountain%20View)

Does anybody know what's going on?  I checked the Google Weather Monitoring link and it says everything is okay.  What the heck is going on? O.o

Answer (score 6):

I have had the same problem over the past few weeks (random 403 errors) with the Unsupported API message appearing last week.

If you ask me, **I think Google has shut the unsuported weather api down for good!** 
Since Google has announced it will shut down iGoogle - for which the api was used for.

I think you need to start looking for a different free weather api (same as me =( ).

If you analyse the iGoogle page with a weather widget you will notice that the call now uses wunderground.com and no more google weather api

eg: http://igoogle.wunderground.com/cgi-bin/findweather/getForecast?query=47.644199,9.180259&unit=SI&hl=de

Comment: So, do you know any free alternatives for this? Thanks.

Comment: @Rocotilos Check out http://openweathermap.org/wiki/API/JSON_API#City_list. I haven't used it yet, but I'm looking at it as an alternative.

Comment: @Jonathan, thanks. Yup I've found that as well, and have successfully implemented it in my app. It's cool, with even more data to use.

Comment: There's [some discussion of alternatives on Slashdot](http://developers.slashdot.org/story/12/09/03/2331203/google-pulls-access-to-unsupported-but-popular-weather-api).

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12145820/google-weather-api-gone/35943521